# If $\exists x_1,x_2,x_3\in \mathbb{R}$ such that they are distinct and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_3)$. Then $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f''(a)=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Prove:**
$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function.
If there $\exists x_1,x_2,x_3\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are distinct and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_3)$. Then $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f''(a)=0$

All I can think of is if there are 3 distinct points where $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_3)$ then this function must be multi-modal, because the only other way their function outputs is equal is if it's constant but a constant function is not twice differentiable. So it must be multi-modal, which means between those points there are critical points where $f'(x)=0$, which means when it hits those peaks $f''(a)=0$, but I don't think that's necessarily a proof.

Comment: A constant function is twice differentiable, for sure.

Comment: y=2 then y'=0 then y''=0 that's still considered differentiable?

Comment: Yes it is. And please note, that the constant function equal to zero is infinite differentiale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume w.l.o.g that $x_1<x_2<x_3$
Apply Rolle's theorem on the intervals $[x_1,x_2]$ and $[x_2,x_3]$

Then exist $y_1 \in [x_1,x_2]$ and $y_2 \in [x_2,x_3]$

such that $f'(y_1)=0=f'(y_2)$

Assume again that $y_1<y_2$

Then apply Rolle on the interval $[y_1,y_2]$